# Database model with Users, Resources, Permissions

Tags: database-design, permissions

I am fairly new to the DB design. I need to handle what a user can do on a specific resource.

One of the main queries I need to drive is:

> Get all the cars a user has write permission to.

I think if I only had the one resource it would be easier, but I will have plenty of resources and so I am trying to design something via a ResourceType model, so that I don't have to create a lot tables as the number of resources grow.

I saw this question: [Discretionary Access Control (DAC) model](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1732/database-model-with-users-roles-and-rights?newreg=c37e24c3b2034bbc91bfa5f95a61c24b)

For what I can tell that is the closest thing to what I am trying to accomplish because it differentiates between roles approach and discretionary. I do not have roles and won't have roles for now. When a user creates a resource (like Car, Location, etc...) the server assigns the "owner" permission for that user. The owner can in turn grant permissions to other users, like read, write...

I have created the following tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE ResourceType
    (
       Id (PK)
       Name
       resourceId
       ...
    )

    CREATE TABLE Car
    (
       Id (PK)
       model
       resourceTypeId (FK to car ResourceType)
       ...
    )

    CREATE TABLE User
    (
       Id (PK)
       Name
       ...
    )

    CREATE TABLE Permission
    (
       Id (PK)
       canRead
       canWrite
       ...
    )
```

then I created a junction table:

```
    CREATE TABLE ResourceTypeToUserPermission
    (
       Id (PK)
       permissionId (FK to Permission)
       resourceTypeId (FK to ResourceType)
       userId (FK to User)
    )
```

I was hoping to use that junction table to get what I needed with inner joins and where clauses on userId = x...

I am obviously not doing this right and I am wondering how I can modify things correctly so that for any resource I will have in the DB  I will be able to get all resources of a given type with a certain type of permission for a given userId.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- User USR exists.
--
user {USR}
  PK {USR}
```

```
-- Resource type RTY exists.
--
res_typ {RTY}
     PK {RTY}
```

```
-- Resource RSC, of resource type RTY,
-- owned by user USR, is named RSC_NAME.
--
resource {RSC, RTY, USR, RSC_NAME}
      PK {RSC}

      SK {RSC, RTY}

      FK1 {RTY} REFERENCES res_typ
      FK2 {USR} REFERENCES user
```

```
-- User USR was granted permission PER to
-- resource RSC by owner of that resource.
--
res_perm {USR, RSC, PER}
      PK {USR, RSC, PER}

FK1 {USR} REFERENCES user
FK2 {RSC} REFERENCES resource

CHECK (PER in ('read', 'write'))
```

Now the resource *subtypes*. The proper way to implement constraints for subtypes would be to use assertions (`CREATE ASSERTION`), but it is still not available in major DBs. I will use `FKs` instead, and as all other substitute methods it is not perfect. People argue a lot, here and on the SO, what is better. I would encourage you to check other methods too.

```
-- Car RSC, resource type 'C', ... car specific.
--
car {RSC, RTY, ... }
 PK {RSC}

 FK {RSC, RTY} REFERENCES resource

 CHECK (RTY = 'C')
```

```
-- Location RSC, resource type 'L', ... location specific.
--
location {RSC, RTY, ... }
      PK {RSC}

      FK {RSC, RTY} REFERENCES resource

      CHECK (RTY = 'L')
```

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
AK = Alternate Key   (Unique)
SK = Proper Superkey (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```

Comment: I'm going to try to implement what you wrote got here and see. Thanks